# UnicodeDecodeError while importing rpy2 in Spyder

Tags: r, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder, rpy2

I've installed rpy2 in Anaconda. This is the code I run:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
```

I encouter error (I've changed username to "myuser"):

```
runfile('D:/Users/myuser/Documents/Python Scripts/regression_test.py', wdir='D:/Users/myuser/Documents/Python Scripts')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "d:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2902, in run_code
    self.showtraceback()

  File "d:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1830, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)

  File "d:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1392, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)

  File "d:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1309, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, elist, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context

  File "d:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 640, in structured_traceback
    lines = ''.join(self._format_exception_only(etype, value))

  File "d:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 752, in _format_exception_only
    Colors.Normal, s))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My software versions:

1. Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)
2. Python 2.7.11
3. R 3.3.1
4. IPython 4.1.2

Does anybody know how to deal with it?

Comment: The versions of Python, R, and rpy2, along with a larger fraction of what Python us reporting about the error would be helpful.

Comment: I've added the information. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback does not show rpy2 code involved, and the details of  `regression_test.py` are not known.

I have seen reports of unicode-related issues with Spyder. Can you try with Python 3 instead of Python 2 ? Python 3 is making the handling of string a little more consistent, and it might solve the issue.